# Have a common header layout in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have 2 pages `user.js` and `nonuser.js` and one component header. `user.js` and `nonuser.js` have same functionality with slight changes in UI. Now I want to integrate all this. Like when I visit the page by default table of `user.js` must be viewed. One click of `nonuser.js` it should change to the `nonuser.js` table. And I want header to be same for both, content in textbox should not change when I switch between pages.

I'm new to next.js and react

header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../Header/header.css';
import { Menu, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import Link from 'next/link';

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar">
                <div className="header">
                    <div className="col-1">

                        <div className="menu">
                            <div>
                                    <Link href="/User"><a>Users</a></Link>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Link href="/nonUser"><a>Non Users</a></Link>
                            </div>
                            <Input className="text-box" placeholder="Enter name" prefix={<Icon type="search" ></Icon>}></Input>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default HeaderComponent
```

user.js

```
class User extends Component {
 render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                   <div className="ant-table-row">
                        <div className="table-head-text">

                            <span className="text">Users({data.length})</span>
                            <Pagination defaultCurrent={1} total={100} />
                        </div>
                        <Table
                            rowKey={data._id}
                            columns={this.columns1}
                            rowSelection={this.rowSelection}
                            onExpand={this.onExpand}
                            dataSource={data} />
                    </div>
         </React.Fragment>
       )
}
```

I didn't add nonuser component, its same as user component

index.js

```
import Header from '../components/Header/header';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
function App() {
 return (
     <Header/>
         <div>

         </div>

 )
}
export default App;
```

I've done this, On first landing the only header is there and on clicking user link in header, header disappears and only table of user is shown.

EDIT: 
I tried this header appears in both and I placed a textbox in header .textbox value clears when I switch between pages.

user.js and nonuser.js

```
 render(){
   return(
            <Layout>
                <div>.....</div>
            </Layout>
    )
 }
```

Also tried
index.js

```
   render() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>

            </div>
        </Layout>

    )
}
```

layout.js

```
const Layout = ({children}) => (


   <div>
     <Header></Header>
     {children}
   </div>

  );
```

Comment: what does that mean "I'm using next.js .totally new to next.js"

Comment: that means new to react with next.js framework .Previously worked in angular

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From what I make of your question, you want to use `HeaderComponent` as a common header for both pages? Then I'd suggest placing it in your `components/Layout` file. Next will wrap all pages in the layout component, thus adding your header to all pages.

I'm also wondering why you have an `index.js` file? Unless it's placed in `pages/` folder, it isn't something you normally do in Next. The pages `user.js` and `nonuser.js` should also be placed in the `pages/` folder. Next will then automatically load the to files and provide them under the routes `/user` and `/nonuser` (based on the name of the file). This will also make Next wrap each page in the layout component mentioned above.

I'd suggest looking into [NextJS learning guide](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started). It provides a very good introduction to NextJS and will make it a lot easier to use NextJS if you. They have a lesson explaining [how to use Shared Components](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/using-shared-components) which explains exactly what you seem to be looking for.

Hope this helps a bit.

Edit:

#### Example using `_app.js`

The following is an example of how to use a custom layout component in next using `_app.js`. It's based on Nexts own [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-app-layout).

```js
// components/Layout.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

class Layout extends Component {
  render () {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
      <div className='layout'>
        <Header />
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// pages/_app.js
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

To get more information on how to make use of `_app.js` properly, check out their [documentation on custom app](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-app).

Comment: user.js and nonuser.js are in pages folder .I have one doubt ,if my header contains textarea and there is text inside.if I swicth between pages will textarea clears the text or reatins that typed value

Comment: hey U mean to say that I have to reuse that layout in user and nonuser pages

Comment: Yes, the layout file is supposed to be used on all pages, according to Next's own documentation. I'm not sure about the textarea though. It would remove the text if the header have to re-render when switching to another page. But if you put it in the layout component and use it on both pages, it most likely wouldn't trigger a re-render when changing page. But that's something you should test, I'm not entirely sure on that one.

Comment: edited my question.We have to use layout page in all the pages and textbox clears when I switch pages .I want it to reatin it .Is there any other ways to achieve through routing in nextjs

Comment: The way you did it will always trigger a re-render of the header when switching to a new page, which causes the textarea to clear. I think you should create a new post with that issue since it isn't really related to the original question, and then mark this post as resolved if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Can we do it using _app.js

Comment: That might be worth a try. Though `_app.js` is normally used to provide things like redux etc., it may be the best solution for your problem.

Comment: I tried _app.js .only header is retained ,when I switch ,url changes but content will not appear .only header is shown

Comment: @Karthi That's probably because you're not setting `_app.js` up as Next documents it. I've edited my answer to provide a concrete example of how to use the layout in `_app.js`.

Comment: textbox clears when I switch between page thats ok .Thanks..Its working.

Comment: Hey I want to send the data from header to appuser.I dont know how to send it  because I have used _app.js

Comment: can we send data from header to other page using props?

Comment: What you are asking for is basic React stuff.  The component header would handle it's own state.  @Krazy

Comment: If you want the text to persist the best option would be to use sessionstorage. For as long as the user keeps the browser/tab window open, it will retain the data set there. It will survive page reloads and restores. You could also use something like Redux, but honestly, unless you want other global states to persist that's too much of a setup just for one thing.