# Is it possible to use once a component for all routes with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, next.js

I'm beginner on NextJS
My problem is simple : I just want to know if is it possible to do this with NextJS

```js
// with react-router-dom
<Router>
    <>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
                <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about">
                <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/users">
                <Users />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </>
</Router>
```

I wish to have `<Header />` in all my pages without rendering each time I change page

Currently I call my header in each page but there is reinitialization of the props.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have a common header layout in nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57918626/have-a-common-header-layout-in-nextjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Next.js you don´t use react-router-dom because Next.js has a file-system based router built on the concept of pages.

The  component can´t be added to the routing, you have to add it in each index page.

Check their documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

Answer (score 0):

You can't and you shouldn't, as switch pattern is already built-in at NextJs.

See related [Migrating from React Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router#basics) section:

> With Next.js, you can express the same application structure in the file system. When a file is added to the pages directory it's automatically available as a route.

```
pages/about.js → /about
pages/blog.js → /blog
pages/index.js → /
```