# How to extend a page in Nextjs. Like a nested switch in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have been using react for sometime,I decided to try out nextjs. I am building a dashboard, that have a side navigation, and several pages will use that sidebar. What i do in reactjs is have a nested switch. And define my routes. Something like this:

```
<Switch>
      <Route path="/pageOne">
        <PageOne />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/pageTwo">
        <pageTwo />
      </Route>
      
    </Switch>
```

but I have gone through a lot of resources, but non seems to talk about extending a page. Another option I am thinking of is to create a subfolder in the dashboard folder, then I will need to import the sidebar component on all the other pages, but this method breaks the DRY principle.

What is the better way to do this?

*EDIT*

This is what I am trying to archive. When I click the links in the sidebar, I navigate just the right side of the page, while the sidebar persists across the page.
[image: Dashboard preview]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have a common header layout in nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57918626/have-a-common-header-layout-in-nextjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're referring to the capacity to dynamically generate pages by appending a given value to some subpage "X" like the behavior that Switch provides, then you should check out the [docs on dynamic router](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Everything in Next is highly reusable, as it's extremely unopinionated about many things

If you want to dynamically generate subsubpages or subsubsubpages even off of some given pages subdirectory, then you can use the [dynamic].tsx filename and generate static paths using `getStaticPaths` followed with `getStaticProps` OR `getServerSideProps` (which does not use getStaticPaths). To clarify, Next's architecture, you are executing on both the server and the client in the same file when using a pages file (excluding pages/** and pages/api* routes). The pages/api routes are serverless node environments and can be fetched from the `default export` on the client of any non-pages/** pages/* file. `getStaticProps` still executes on the server and therefore contributes 0 to your bundle size. Same goes for `getStaticPaths`. You only need the latter when using `getStaticProps` within a dynamic file-type (`[dynamic].tsx [...dynamic-catch-all].tsx, [[...dynamic-catch-all-optional]].tsx`)

check out my profile for some [repos](https://github.com/DopamineDriven/github-search-graphql) with dynamic routing if you'd like

If I'm being honest I had to refresh myself on what the `Switch` wrapper achieves in CRApp because it's been so long since I've worked in it. I have been using Next with TSX for over a yr now so feel free to shoot any follow up ?s.

Here's an example from a recent client project which dynamically generates 25+ gallery subpages during build

`components/Gallery/gallery.tsx`

```
import Image, { ImageLoaderProps } from 'next/image';
import { Timestamp, Container } from '@/components/UI/index';
import { parseUrl } from '@/lib/helpers';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Gallery } from '@/types/booksy/media';

export default function GalleryMapped({
    images,
    images_count,
    images_per_page
}: Gallery) {
    const GalleryImageLoader = ({
        src,
        width,
        quality
    }: ImageLoaderProps) => {
        return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
    };
    return (
        <Container className='max-w-7xl mx-auto m-12 container'>
            <ul
                role='list'
                className='grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-3 max-w-7xl mx-auto'
            >
                <span className='sr-only'>{images_per_page}</span>
                {images
                    .map((photo, i) => {
                        const targetedThumbnail = photo.thumbnails['640,0-hr'].url;
                        // console.log('target: ', targetedThumbnail);
                        const thumbnailDecoded = decodeURI(targetedThumbnail);
                        // console.log('decoded: ', thumbnailDecoded);
                        const fragmentThumbnailURI = parseUrl(thumbnailDecoded);
                        // console.log('URI Fragments: ', fragmentThumbnailURI);
                        const thumbnailReconstructed = `${fragmentThumbnailURI!.baseUrl.concat(
                            fragmentThumbnailURI!.pathname
                        )}`;
                        // console.log('reconstructed: ', thumbnailReconstructed);

                        return (
                            <li key={i++} className='relative'>
                                <div className='group cover block w-full rounded-xl bg-redditBG focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-offset-gray-100 focus-within:ring-indigo-500 overflow-hidden'>
                                    <Link
                                        href='/gallery/[id]'
                                        as={`/gallery/${photo.image_id}`}
                                        passHref
                                        shallow={true}
                                        scroll={true}
                                    >
                                        <a id={`/gallery#${photo.image_id}`}>
                                            <Image
                                                loader={GalleryImageLoader}
                                                src={thumbnailReconstructed ?? photo.image}
                                                width='1280'
                                                height='1294'
                                                alt={`${photo.description ?? photo.category}`}
                                                quality={100}
                                                className='object-cover pointer-events-none group-hover:opacity-75 shadow-cardHover'
                                            />
                                        </a>
                                    </Link>
                                    <button
                                        type='button'
                                        className='absolute inset-0 focus:outline-none'
                                    >
                                        <span className='sr-only'>
                                            View details for {photo.image_id}
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <p className='mt-2 block text-sm font-medium text-olive-300 truncate pointer-events-none'>
                                    <Timestamp timestamp={photo.created} />
                                </p>
                                <p className='block text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 pointer-events-none'>
                                    {`${++i}/${images_count}`}
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })
                    .reverse()}
            </ul>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Then, it's imported into the `pages/gallery/[id].tsx` where `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` are injected with server-fed props of the current incoming data by apollo client and SWR.

`pages/Gallery/[id].tsx`

```
import {
    GetStaticPropsContext,
    GetStaticPropsResult,
    GetStaticPathsContext,
    InferGetStaticPropsType
} from 'next';
import { initializeApollo, addApolloState } from '@/lib/apollo';
import {
    DynamicNavDocument,
    DynamicNavQueryVariables,
    DynamicNavQuery,
    WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum
} from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';
import { AppLayout } from '@/components/Layout';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Container, Fallback } from '@/components/UI';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { fetcherGallery } from '@/lib/swr-fetcher';
import { Gallery } from '@/types/booksy/media';
import { Configuration, Fetcher } from 'swr/dist/types';
import {
    getLatestBooksyPhotos,
    getBooksyPhotoById
} from '@/lib/booksy';
import Image, { ImageLoaderProps } from 'next/image';
import { parseUrl } from '@/lib/helpers';

export async function getStaticPaths({
    locales
}: GetStaticPathsContext): Promise<{
    paths: string[];
    fallback: false;
}> {
    const data: Response = await getLatestBooksyPhotos();
    const pathsData: Gallery = await data.json();

    return {
        paths: locales
            ? locales.reduce<string[]>((arr, locale) => {
                    pathsData.images.forEach(imageId => {
                        arr.push(`/${locale}/gallery/${imageId.image_id}`);
                    });
                    return arr;
              }, [])
            : pathsData?.images.map(
                    imageId => `/gallery/${imageId.image_id}`
              ),
        fallback: false
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps<P>(
    ctx: GetStaticPropsContext
): Promise<
    GetStaticPropsResult<
        P & {
            Header: DynamicNavQuery['Header'];
            Footer: DynamicNavQuery['Footer'];
            initDataImage: Partial<
                Configuration<Gallery, any, Fetcher<Gallery>>
            >;
            id: string;
        }
    >
> {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo({
        headers: ctx.params ?? {}
    });

    await apolloClient.query<
        DynamicNavQuery,
        DynamicNavQueryVariables
    >({
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
        query: DynamicNavDocument,
        variables: {
            idHead: 'Header',
            idTypeHead: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idTypeFoot: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idFoot: 'Footer'
        }
    });
    const id = ctx?.params ? (ctx.params.id as string) : '21177790';
    const initDataGallery = await getBooksyPhotoById(id);
    const initDataImage: Gallery = await initDataGallery.json();

    return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
        props: {
            initDataImage,
            id
        },
        revalidate: 600
    });
}

export default function GalleryById<
    T extends typeof getStaticProps
>({
    Header,
    Footer,
    initDataImage,
    id
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<T>) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const parsedId = router.query
        ? (router.query.id as string)
        : '';

    const { data } = useSWR<Gallery>(
        `/api/booksy-image-by-id/?category=biz_photo&image_id=${
            id ? id : parsedId
        }`,
        fetcherGallery,
        initDataImage
    );

    const booksyImageLoader = ({
        src,
        width,
        quality
    }: ImageLoaderProps) => {
        return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
    };

    const targetThumbnail = data?.images[0].thumbnails['640,0-hr']
        .url
        ? data.images[0].thumbnails['640,0-hr'].url
        : data?.images[0].image
        ? data.images[0].image
        : '';

    const thumbnailDecoded = decodeURI(targetThumbnail ?? '');

    const fragmentThumbnailURI = parseUrl(thumbnailDecoded ?? '');

    const thumbnailReconstructed =
        `${fragmentThumbnailURI?.baseUrl.concat(
            fragmentThumbnailURI.pathname
        )}
` ?? '';

    return (
        <>
            {router.isFallback ? (
                <Fallback />
            ) : (
                <AppLayout
                    Header={Header}
                    Footer={Footer}
                    title={`${data?.images[0].image_id ?? parsedId}`}
                >
                    <Container
                        clean
                        className='my-16 max-w-5xl mx-auto block rounded-xl shadow-cardHover'
                    >
                        {data && data.images ? (
                            <Image
                                className='rounded-xl object-cover'
                                src={
                                    thumbnailReconstructed !== ''
                                        ? thumbnailReconstructed
                                        : '/doge-404.jpg'
                                }
                                loader={booksyImageLoader}
                                width='1280'
                                height='1294'
                                priority
                                quality={100}
                                layout='responsive'
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Fallback />
                        )}
                    </Container>
                </AppLayout>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

The directory [image: looks like this]

and there are 48 paths being generated in production builds at the moment

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Ross for your answer,  I learned something here. However, I think you didn't get my question. I have edited the question